# Upload file doesn't save to specify folder, throw error

Tags: php

The error is Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/cv/23456543555555CURRICULUM VITAE.doc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\job-application\include\application.class.php on line 121

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php7EA1.tmp' to 'uploads/cv/23456543555555CURRICULUM VITAE.doc' in C:\wamp\www\job-application\include\application.class.php on line 121

The code follows below;

```
$allowedExtsDoc = array("docx", "pdf", "doc");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extensionDoc = end($temp);
            $uploaddircv = 'uploads/cv/';
            $uploadfilecv = $uploaddircv . basename($phone.$_FILES['file']['name']);
            if (in_array($extensionDoc, $allowedExtsDoc))
                {
                    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                    {
                        $this->error .= $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        if (file_exists($uploaddircv . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                        {
                            $this->error .= $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. <br/>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$uploadfilecv);
                            $fileloc = $this->sitePath.$uploadfilecv;
                        }
                    }
                }
            else
            {
                $this->error .= "Invalid file <br/>";
            }
```

Comment: `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` seems to be _empty_? The error message shows you seem to be missing an argument in `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen its not empty. I have edited the and addes the second error

Comment: looks like your folder path is incorrect or the folder isn't created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the directories: `C:\wamp\tmp\` and `uploads/cv/` exists and are writable by Apache.

After that, try to use the complete path to uploads folder.

```
$uploaddircv = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../uploads/cv/') . '/';
```

Comment: as a side not the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` could be used to make sure that PHP uses the correct path separator for the OS it runs on

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov: Yeah, but under Windows using `/` works perfectly as well, so no _real_ need for that in most cases.

Comment: @lucasvscn The move_uploaded_file() looks for the uploads/cv/ dir Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php76AB.tmp' to 'C:\wamp\www\job-application\include/uploads/cv/34567876555CURRICULUM VITAE.doc' in C:\wamp\www\job-application\include\application.class.php on line 121 rather than C:\wamp\www\job-application\uploads\cv\

Comment: I want it to store the file here C:\wamp\www\job-application\uploads\cv\ rather than C:\wamp\www\job-application\include/uploads/cv/34567876555CURRICULUM VITAE.doc which is not available

Comment: @Josiah I've changed the code sample, in my response. You can add /../ to go back to previous directory (in this case, job-application\).